# How to define a funciton without the explicit defination in Maple?

Tags: maple, mathematica

I want to define a funtion in Maple like:

> g(t,r,theta,phi)

but without the explicit defination.
Thus, when I try to run

> diff(g,t)

I hope it can give(only the formular, not(also it cant) the value)

> $g_t(t,r,theta,phi)$

or

> $\frac{d g(t,r,theta,phi)}{dt}$

I know mathematica can do this, but I want to use the DifferentialGeometry  module in Maple.

Thanks you all.
Best wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, diff knows only expressions not functions, so it is

```
> diff(g(r,t,theta,phi),t);
```

You can possibly try this

```
> g:=G(r,t,theta,phi);
> diff(g,t);
```

But you won't be able to do much with $g$ anyway.